# Windows 7 kinect drivers

Tags: windows, windows-7, kinect, drivers, kinect-sdk

I have a question about the Kinect for windows.
I am trying to install the kinect drivers, but I have a problem.
My pc doesn't recognize the kinect drivers.
I have installed the SDK, Development Kit and the Runtime setup.
Does anyone know why my pc doesn't recognize the drivers and how i can solve that?
Thank you very much already.
Gr. Gilian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my windows 7 has solved the problem.